Mongoose: Cómo filtrar por rango de fechas a un documento que también posee un intervalo de fechas
tengo una duda a la hora de crear el pipeline para buscar las vacantes.
Mi problema es el siguiente, poseo la siguiente colección:
IEvent {
  _id: any;
  title: string;
  // Otros atributos
  startDate?: Date;
  endDate?: Date;
}

Y tengo una tabla que filtra las vacantes por rango de fechas: "FInit" y "FEnd".
Mi duda es cómo debo hacer el match en el pipeline del aggregate Vacant, para que me traiga aquellos documentos donde el intervalo startDate y el endDate intersecten (incluyendo los extremos [startDate, endDate]) con el intervalo de fechas que coloca el usuario en el filtro.
